# Storing emojies in mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to store emojies in mysql (version 5.7.18).

My table structure looks like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE `message_message` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `created_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `is_read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `chat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

I am trying to save emojies in `message` field only and I can see that it gets saved with question marks (`?☺️???`).

Is there a way for me to read these values directly from the table (actually I would like to see emojies in table viewer). I am using SequelPro for viewing table (if that matters).

Exact mysql query that I am running

`INSERT INTO message_message(message, created_at, msg_sender_id, chat_id, is_read) VALUES ('', UTC_TIME(), 110, 164, False)`

If I run select query on this table, it looks like this:

`+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| message                                                             |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                    |
|                                                                  |
|                                                                   |
|                                                                   |
|                                                                   |
|`

Does this looks like data is stored correctly?

Comment: Show the exact bytes (hex) you store and exact bytes stored. Also, what is the client connection character set?

Comment: @zerkms the client connection character set is `utf8mb4`. I attached piece of sql that I am using to insert data.

Comment: If the client connection charset is `utf8mb4`, and the source query is properly encoded as `utf8`, and a column has proper charset - then the data is inserted correctly.

Comment: @zerkms thanks for explaining. But how would I be able to actually see the correctly rendered items in table viewer (for example SequelPro)? Does it matter if I change table charset / collation?

Comment: If your question is specifically about SequelPro - contact their support about whether their product supports multibyte utf8 characters or not. This is a development community actually. If the data is stored correctly (which you still need to confirm though) - then all good :-)

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for clarification! The question is about if data is stored correctly and how can I confirm that (doesn't matter which viewer I use). I have added output how it shows when I do a query through console. Does this seems correct to you? My biggest concern is if this data should be converted to some other format before saving it to database? Other than that for me it seems correct :)

Comment: Just check the `SELECT hex(message)`. Then compare with your expected bytes. If those match - then it's inserted properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159353/discussion-between-bla0009-and-zerkms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, your data is stored correctly.

You provided this string `F09F9281F09F918D` as a result for `SELECT hex(message)` for the data inserted with

```
INSERT INTO message_message(message, created_at, msg_sender_id, chat_id, is_read) VALUES ('', UTC_TIME(), 110, 164, False)
```

And if one checks the UTF8 for both emojis:

- `F0 9F 92 81` for
- `F0 9F 91 8D` for

then you would find that those exactly match with what you already have.

It means your code is correct and if you have any problems with your GUI application - it's a GUI application configuration or unicode support issues and is a bit out of topic for the stackoverflow.

References:

- https://unicode-table.com/en/1F481/
- https://unicode-table.com/en/1F44D/

Answer (score 1):

I think your table collation must be properly configured too:

```
 CREATE TABLE `message_message` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `created_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `is_read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `chat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

Comment: The charset and collation for the field are already set. When it's set for a field explicitly the table one does not make any influence on it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your table collation is `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin`, to update this (in your case), the query would be:

```
ALTER TABLE message_message CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
```

Make sure your database's default collation is `utf8mb4`, to update this, the query would be:

```
SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S WHERE schema_name = "DBNAME";
```

Comment: Table collation does not affect anything as soon as the column charset and collation are set.